# DocumentCompleted event when the page is fully loaded in WebBrowser form (Windows Forms C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use the DocumentCompleted but this gets fired multiple times. Now I've seen this example `if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != this.webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath)` which is used to confirm that the requested file is completed loading but this gets fired before anything else (like images) on the page is loaded. Thus I'm still not able to tell when a webpage is fully loaded.

Is there a way to ensure that the webpage has fully loaded and there's nothing being loaded?

Comment: In my experience, `DocumentCompleted` shouldn't get fired multiple times. Do you have some URL redirecting going on?

Comment: @lc. I'm just opening www.hotmail.com right now on the WebBrowser(i need to open this page but will need to open others) So I'm guessing that might be redirecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DocumentCompleted` event is fired for each frame in the web page and also for all the child documents (e.g. JS and CSS) that are loaded. You could look at the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` in `DocumentCompleted` and check the Url property and compare that to the Url of the main page.

The easy way is to check the URL that completed loading:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) {
        // Here the page is fully loaded        
    }
}
```

Comment: Like i've said in the question, I've used this equality but this event actually gets fired first (before all the other forms) So in fact when that if statement is true, the page is not fully loaded (none of the frames are loaded).. Using this does not provide me with the ability to tell when the page has fully loaded